# Error after upload file submit in ExtJS 3.4

Tags: extjs

After added file i get two errors:

```
   Blocked a frame with origin "http://host:8080" from accessing a frame with origin "http://host". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. ext-all.js:3922
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

html code:

```
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
        handler: function(){
            if(loadfile.getForm().isValid()){
                    loadfile.getForm().submit({
                        url: 'http://host/test/file-upload.php?path='+r.get('dtp'),
                        waitMsg: 'Сохранение фотографии...',
                        success: function(loadfile, o){
                        var data = Ext.decode(o.response.responseText);
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', data.msg);
                        },
                        failure: function(loadfile, o){
                        var data = Ext.decode(o.response.responseText);
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', data.msg);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    },{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function(){
            loadfile.getForm().reset();
        }
    }]
```

php code:

```
     <?php
          $uploaddir = '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/test/upload/'.$_GET["path"];
          if (!is_dir($uploaddir))
             {
               mkdir($uploaddir, 0777);
             }
          $uploaddir.='/';
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$_FILES['userfile']['name']))
             {
               echo '("success": true, "msg": "Файл успешно сохранён.")';
             } else {
               echo '{"success": false, "msg": "Файл не сохранён!"}';
             }
     ?>
```

If set in html like this(without changed php code):

```
                        success: function(loadfile, o){
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Success upload file');
                        },
                        failure: function(loadfile, o){
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Failure upload file');
                        }
```

i get only one error:

```
        Blocked a frame with origin "http://host:8080" from accessing a frame with origin "http://host". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

and all files uploading successful(for two examples).

Answer (score 0):

The error messages says it all, you're making a forbidden cross domain requests. "Protocols, domains, and ports must match." so `host:8080` is considered a different domain than `host`.

Change your `url` to simply `'/test/file-upload.php?path=' + r.get('dtp')` and it should work.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/298745/1387519) for more information and other possible solutions.

Your second error comes from the fact that your trying to decode something that is not JSON, nor Javascript (something like an error message), and that `Ext.decode` use `eval` on it.

**Update**

You've got another error in your PHP. Brackets should be curly in this line:

```
echo '("success": true, "msg": "Файл успешно сохранён.")';
```

You should use `json_encode` and PHP will take care of this for you:

```
$data = array('success' => true, 'msg' => '...');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: i set like '/test/file-upload.php?path=' + r.get('dtp') and i have only one error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <.

Comment: What is the content of the response body? You can see it in the net panel of the dev tools or output it in the console (`console.log(o.response.responseText)`).

Comment: "<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">&lt;?php
$uploaddir = '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/test/upload/';//.$_GET["path"];
if (!is_dir($uploaddir))
  {
    mkdir($uploaddir, 0777);
  }
$uploaddir.='/';

Comment: if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir .
 $_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
   echo "success";
} else {
   echo "error";
}
?&gt;
</pre>"

Comment: i undestand: my html http://host:8080/my.html but my php on http://host/my.php and in tomcat6(port 8080) no execute php, my php execute on apache only.

Comment: Yes, that was the cause of the cross domain issue. Now, it also seems from the response that your PHP doesn't get executed. Try accessing your PHP directly from your browser and make it work from there before debugging the JS.

Comment: i think 'submit()' dont undestand what callback my php... my error after "doDecode = function(json) {return eval("(" + json + ")")}"

Comment: any help me?zzzzzzzzzz

Comment: Sorry but no. I pointed several problems, but you didn't make clear what you have understood, what you have fixed, and what is the problem now. I don't even know what is your code now, and I am not willing to play guessing.

Comment: ok, sorry. My problem have two error how in question. First error about my php starting on apache(html in tomcat6 without php support). Second error about loadfile.getForm().submit({success:...}) - dont undestand what returned my php(url: 'http://host/test/file-upload.php?path='+r.get('dtp')) - php return this: {"success": true, "msg": "success.."}.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in Extjs that has already been identified.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136092-Response-lost-from-upload-Ajax-request-to-iframe-if-document.domain-changed

Please see the workaround in the post